# Passing in an ActiveRecord scope as a filter_by string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of scopes in my model which need to be filters in an admin panel.

periodical.rb

```
class Periodical < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :archived_newspaper, where("category = 'Newspaper'").where("archived = ?", true)
  scope :current_magazine, where("category = 'Magazine'").where("archived = ?", false)
end
```

index.html.erb

```
Filter by: <a href="?filter_by=archived_newspaper">Archived Newspapers</a>
  <a href="?filter_by=current_magazine">Current Magazines</a>
```

How would you implement the controller given that there would be other typical things like pagination, search, sort, etc.?

```
class PeriodicalController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @periodicals = Periodical.page(params[:page])
    @periodicals = @periodicals.order(params[:sort_by]) if !params[:sort_by].blank?
    # Scope here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution since there are certainly security concerns with it, but you could do something like this:

```
class PeriodicalController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @periodicals = Periodical.page(params[:page])
    @periodicals = @periodicals.order(params[:sort_by]) unless params[:sort_by].blank?

    if params[:filter_by] and Periodical.respond_to?(params[:filter_by].to_sym)
      begin
        new_scope = Periodical.send(params[:filter_by].to_sym)
        new_scope = nil unless new_scope.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
      rescue ArgumentError
        new_scope = nil
      end
      @periodicals.merge(new_scope)
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** some alternatives:

1) Filter the param to a list of permissible scopes (better protecting the Periodical model from attack by people editing the parameters in the request):

```
filter_by = params[:filter_by].to_sym
if [:archived_magazine, :current_magazine].include?(filter_by)
  new_scope = Periodical.send(params[:filter_by].to_sym)
  @periodicals.merge(new_scope)  
end
```

2) use a case / switch and hard code the scopes (better security, but not very DRY)

```
new_scope = case params[:filter_by]
  when "archived_magazine"
    Periodical.archived_magazine
  when "current_magazine"
    Periodical.current_magazine
  else 
    nil
end
@periodicals.merge(new_scope)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not the greatest fan, but you can protect it reasonably well, they way i've coded it will only let the filter_by param pull 0 arity scope method from the Periodical model. The only other way would be to explicitly code the permissibly filter_by values into the controller (and still use a send), or use a case/switch and hard code the scopes. Will edit to show what i mean

Comment: @gominimal the send shouldn't make you nervous. It's a part of Ruby and a useful one. Make sure your methods don't take params and don't send a method with params and there's no security concern.